# styling elements inside ui:repeat by css

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm displaying a list of elements using

```
<ui:repeat value="#{itemDetail.imageUrlsList}" var="imageUrl" class="thumbnail">    
    <div class="thumbnail" >
        <a4j:commandLink id="thumbLink" 
            actionListener="#{itemDetail.setCurrentImageUrl(imageUrl)}" 
            render="mainProductPic" immediate="true" >
             <h:graphicImage  id="thumbPic" value="/image/#{imageUrl}" width="50" height="50" />
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

this generate html like for each element on the list :

```
<a href="#" />
```

without css class to define.

Could anyone tell me how to specify class from ui:repeat to have this html for each element on the list :

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb" />
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it , I just added `styleclass` attribute in the `a4j:commandlink` like this:

```
< a4j:commandLink id="thumbLink" styleClass="thumbnail" />
```

Hope that will help someone.